# Why Microsoft Lync/Skype for Business creates a different chat each time I have to chat with a person?

Tags: skype, lync-2013

I have been using Lync for about 2 years now at work however this thing where it creates a new chat each time I wanna communicate with same person is horrible. It makes searching something in it seems like a huge task.
Is there any way around this?
Is there any good reason for creating separate chat even if its the same person m talking with?

Comment: which version did you use? Are you still using Lync and not Skype for Business? Because with Skype for Business I couldn´t really reproduce the issue.

Comment: I got update for Skype for Business, however the Help->about page still says Microsoft Lync 1013(15.0.4875.1001).

Comment: and the underlaying server? Do you know if that is still lync or skype for business?

Comment: I am not sure on the server. I will check it with the technical team.

Comment: @BastianW in Skype for Business is it a single conversion with a single contact format?